Fixed Effects OLS Estimation in R and what various specifications mean
I have a question about panel data related to feols in R.
Suppose that I have the linear regression model
y_{it}=a+x_{1it}+x_{2it}+error_{it}

where i=1,...,T is country index and t=1,...,T is the period.
In R, I run these model
   model A  feols(y~  x1| Country[x2], data = mydata)  
   model B  feols(y~  x1+Country/x2, data = mydata)  
   model C  feols(y~  x1+i(Country,x2), data = mydata)  
   model D  feols(y~  x1+i(Country,x2)|Country, data = mydata)
   model E  feols(y~  x1 |Country^year, data = mydata) 
   model F  feols(y~  x1 |Country^year+c(Country,year), data = mydata) 
   model G  feols(y~  x1 |Country[year]+c(Country,year), data = mydata) 

where my data contains the columns 'Country' and 'year' .
What are the econometric specifications corresponding to these R models?
My try:
Model A:  y_{it}=x_{1it}+a_i*x_{2it}+error_{it}, where a_i is the country-specific effect.

Model B:  I read that model B delives the same estimation results with model A, but what is its econometric specification?

Model C: y_{it}=x_{1it}+Country_1*x_{2it}+Country_2*x_{2it}+...+Country_N*x_{2it} +error_{it}

where Country_1,...,Country_N are dummy variables.

Model D: y_{it}=a_i+x_{1it}+Country_1*x_{2it}+Country_2*x_{2it}+...+Country_N*x_{2it} +error_{it}

where Country_1,...,Country_N are dummy variables.

Model E: y_{it}=a_i*lambda_t+x_{1it} +error_{it}, where lambda_t is time fixed effects


Welcome to the site. This is more of a programming question so it may get migrated to Stack Overflow. In the meantime, you can try to edit it to clarify your statistical question.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/fixest_walkthrough.html

Thank you very much!

From Stack Overflow they told me that my question was irrelevant and they closed it. So any ideas from Stack Exchange? Thank you!

Actually I read it too fast. This is relevant here. You may want to edit it to render most of your question as MathJax / latex instead of code.
